# Receiving 'Unknown column 'Dense_Rank' in 'where clause' in MySQL Workbench error

Tags: mysql, sql

First time poster here so I'd like to preemptively thank everyone for their help.

I'm trying to rank the records of a table and further specify the output using a WHERE clause. However, I'm receiving the error message stated on my post title.

```
SELECT Name, Gender, Salary,
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS `Rank`,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) AS `Dense_Rank`
FROM employees
;
```

Yields the result [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKRyx.png). Easy peasy.

When I then add the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT Name, Gender, Salary,
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS `Rank`,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) AS `Dense_Rank`
FROM employees
WHERE `Dense_Rank` = 2
;
```

I get 'Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Dense_Rank' in 'where clause'

I've tried different methods to avail; omitting the backticks and using a different alias, using HAVING instead of WHERE - no luck. Plz halp.

Comment: You cannot use a column alias in the `where` clause.  Use a subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use subquery;

```
Select * from
(
SELECT Name, Gender, Salary,
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS `Rank`,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) AS `Dense_Rank`
FROM employees
) X
WHERE `Dense_Rank` = 2
```

Comment: Holy shit, that worked perfectly - thank you! Do you mind explaining why it needed to be in a subquery? Or point me in the direction of a source to read over?

Comment: Reektheunbroken, because in Standard SQL you won't be able to refer to column's alias in the WHERE clause. That's why you can use subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a column alias in a `where` clause.  MySQL extends the use of `having`, so you can use that:

```
SELECT Name, Gender, Salary,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS `Rank`,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) AS `Dense_Rank`
FROM employees
HAVING `Dense_Rank` = 2
```

Comment: Oddly enough, when I used HAVING, I received a different error message entirely: Error Code: 3594. You cannot use the alias 'Dense_Rank' of an expression containing a window function in this context.'

Comment: You can't use this either , because alias of an expression containing window function can't be used with 'WHERE' and 'Having' both